# Use of a key value store for keeping indexes of rdbms

Tags: database, elasticsearch, solr, key-value-store

Let me describe the problem. I have a quite big RDBMS database with around 10TB of data, many of them big blobs with documents. Search with id's are very fast but as expected more specific searches based on other data are really really slow.

We are considering the approach keep indexing of our documents in sth like a solr or another key value store, the application will ask it for the id and then will make an id based search in rdbms for the data.

The above approach is it considered a good practice ?

For now we don't think the possibility to change or redesign our rdbms (although we should), that's why we are looking for this kind of alternatives.

Thanks for any possible help.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the queries you might need to rely on an external database whether it is solr, elasticsearch or even wiredtiger depends on your needs and the kinds of queries and workload you have.

That said, you might consider the use of [materialized view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view).